# How can I obfuscate XML resource files with DexGuard?

Tags: android, xml, resources, dexguard

I am using to DexGuard to process my android applications.
On DexGuard's Homepage they say it features: XML resource obfuscation

I already tested DexGuard and decompiled my output .apks with apktool.
The problem is ALL resource files are decompiled succesffully, so they have not been obfuscated  apparently.

Now my question is, does DexGuard automatically obfuscate XML resources or do i have to activate it somehow in my dexguard-project.txt file?
Is it possible to obfuscate XML resources like strings.xml or am I misunderstanding this feature?

Comment: Did you open one of the XML files and look at it? `More obfuscation of resource XML files. DexGuard now makes the files even less readable and hardens them against tampering.` Just looks like it jumbles them up internally rather than renaming the file itself

Comment: Yes I opened them and compared them to my actual resource files. They are completely equal to the dexguard outputs.
(Other features like asset/class/string encryption did work btw.)

Comment: same thing happened with me,xml resources are decompiled successfully but not source code. do u find any solution @user2350644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the following statement from DexGuard:

> Resource XML files are obfuscated automatically in release builds,
>   although the ***differences may be subtle***. You can compare the
>   differences with for instance aapt d xmltree application.apk
>   AndroidManifest.xml. We are working on more obfuscation of resources
>   for upcoming versions.

After executing the proposed command `aapt d xmltree application.apk` (where application.apk is a simple HelloWorld Application) i finally could see what DexGuard actually obfuscates in XML files:

Each attribute in an XML resource file is identified by a name, but often also by a numeric identifier.  In AndroidManifest.xml for example:

`android:versionName(0x010102lc) = "1.0"`

In the obfuscation step, DexGuard can remove the name of an attribute, but only if this attribute also has a numeric identifier.

After DexGuard obfuscation the above attribute will look like this:

`:(0x010102lc) = "1.0"`

As XML elements of strings.xml for instance only have a name and no numeric identifier, there won't be any differences in the decompiled XML file.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to obfuscate strings.xml? is it because you have api keys or oauth secrets in there? If so, then better to move them to assets/config.properties file and load to a `java.util.Properties` object like this...

```
Properties appConfigProperties = new Properties();
appConfigProperties.load(context.getAssets().open("config.properties"))
String myApiKey = appConfigProperties.get("my_api_key");
```

*(for brevity I've removed the exception handling)*

Be sure to enable asset encryption in your DexGuard config file:

```
-encryptassetfiles assets/**
```